# How to get dojo data grid cell in edit mode by default

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am looking to get dojo datagrid appear by default in edit mode. How can this be accomplished?

Or Can this invoked programmatically outside of grid?

Comment: Set `alwaysEditing` to true on each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the Grid:

```
editable = true;
```

You should also take a look at:
http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojox/grid/DataGrid

Comment: That would only make it editable on single or double click, I need it by default in edit mode i.e. when grid loads it should be text boxes not just as labels. Anyways I found solution to it, in layout with each cell(or one you want to be in edit mode) define alwaysEditing:true.

Answer (score 0):

while in layout structure i'm declaring this

```
gridStructure = [{
    defaultCell: { ..., editable: true}
    , cells:[ ...,
        {field: "COLUMNx", name: "Column X"}
    ]
}];
```

defaultCell get the same parameter as cells